# Django settings __init__.py not respected by gitignore

Tags: git, django-settings

in my Django project, I have organised the settings as a module with a file structure like this:

```
/settings/
  __init__.py
  base.py
  prod.py
  dev.py
  dev_user_a.py
  dev_user_b.py
  prod_user_a.py
  prod_user_b.py    etc.
```

They are working as a hierarchy, i.e. `def_user_a.py` imports `dev.py`, `dev.py` imports `base.py`.
`__init__.py` imports one of the 'leaves', i.e. `dev_user_a.py`, this is how each user can choose his settings. This works fine, except that I cannot seem to exclude `/settings/__init__.py` from git, which means local changes to this file are likely to be accidentally broadcasted to other users.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to achieve this, and how?
2. Why does adding `__init__.py` to `.gitignore` (or `.git/info/exclude`) not work?

Comment: Has it already been committed?

Comment: Yes, by another user, then I pulled it, unawares that this was happening, and for a while worked on his settings. Now I've changed it back to my values, and I haven't staged it, but it keeps hanging around in my uncomitted changes. When I try git check-ignore trees/trees/settings/*, it correctly lists settings/dev_xxx.py, but not __init__.py

Comment: .gitignore contains (amongst other stuff) those two lines
trees/trees/settings/__init__.py
trees/trees/settings/dev_*.py

Comment: If it's being tracked then it won't be ignored.

Comment: Ah, I had to use git rm --cached trees/trees/__init__.py, thanks.

Comment: Sure, but remember that this will remove it from git for the other use too (if they merge or use your branch)

Comment: "*…this will remove it from git for the other use too (if they merge or use your branch)*" This will remove the file from the working tree even for @AngelikaSajani when she switches to a different branch and then back.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297002/django-settings-init-py-not-respected-by-gitignore#comment118951717_67297002), a *tracked* file is not going to be ignored, even if its name is listed in an exclusion file.  See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/1256452).  Note that a tracked file is any file that is currently in Git's *index* and a committed file will be extracted into Git's index during `git checkout`, so any committed file becomes tracked by default.

It's important *not* to omit or remove `__init__.py` since its presence turns a module into a "package": see [§6.4 of the official Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for instance.  Removing it will remove the package-ness of this directory.

In this particular case, the `__init__.py` file should probably just be *empty*.  Users can import the correct settings directly.  Or, because this is a Django setup, they should probably use the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable instead, as described in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/).  (Note: Django users may have better answers here.  I have never used Django myself.)